Interop call multiple times for same file but with different values
I am working on small semi Hobi project for my home office.
My code takes data from 10 input field (in code shown here I truncated it to 4 for readability), do some work on that data and then try to open Word template file to populate it with those data. Problem is that sometimes I need only one field (so only one file will be open) but some times I need 2, 5 or 10. When I want to open more than one file my code do everything correctly but all files are populated with data from last input field (instead that file 1 has data from field1, file 2 has data from field 2...).
For example
InputField 1 -> Data 1
InputField 2 -> Data 2
InputField 3 -> Data 3

should result in opening three files with data1 in first, data 2 in second and Data 3 in third, but I get three files all populated with Data 3 (or whatever field is last, so basicly it only works correctly when there is only one field populated).
This is code that is preparing Data:
private void OtvoriBanke(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Dictionary<string, string> placeholderValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     var template = "";
     string otvori_printaj = "1";
     List<string> BANKA_NAZIV = new List<string> {};
     List<string> BANKA_ADRESA = new List<string> { };
     List<string> BANKA_GRAD = new List<string> { };



     if (OstavineBanke_BEZPRINTANJA.IsChecked == true) { otvori_printaj = "0"; }

         
       template = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cfg_GlavniFolder"] + "\\banke\\o_BANKE_m.dotx";
    
     if (OstavineB1_poslati.IsChecked == true)
     {

         BANKA_NAZIV.Add(OstavineB1_banka.Text);
         BANKA_ADRESA.Add(OstavineB1_adresa.Text);
         BANKA_GRAD.Add(OstavineB1_grad.Text);
     }

     if (OstavineB2_poslati.IsChecked == true)
     {
         BANKA_NAZIV.Add(OstavineB2_banka.Text);
         BANKA_ADRESA.Add(OstavineB2_adresa.Text);
         BANKA_GRAD.Add(OstavineB2_grad.Text);
     }

     if (OstavineB3_poslati.IsChecked == true)
     {
         BANKA_NAZIV.Add(OstavineB3_banka.Text);
         BANKA_ADRESA.Add(OstavineB3_adresa.Text);
         BANKA_GRAD.Add(OstavineB3_grad.Text);
     }
     if (OstavineB4_poslati.IsChecked == true)
     {
         BANKA_NAZIV.Add(OstavineB4_banka.Text);
         BANKA_ADRESA.Add(OstavineB4_adresa.Text);
         BANKA_GRAD.Add(OstavineB4_grad.Text);
     }
    
     Dictionary<string, string>[] matrix = new Dictionary<string, string>[]
     {
             new Dictionary<string, string>(),
             new Dictionary<string, string>(),
             new Dictionary<string, string>(),
             new Dictionary<string, string>()
                
     };

     for (int i = 0; i < BANKA_NAZIV.Count(); i++)
     {
         
           placeholderValues["<BANKA>"] = BANKA_NAZIV[i];
           placeholderValues["<ADRESA>"] = BANKA_ADRESA[i];
           placeholderValues["<GRAD_BANKA>"] = BANKA_GRAD[i];

           matrix[i] = placeholderValues;

    }

     

     Thread thread = new Thread(() => WordPrint.WordPrint.FindReplacePrint_T(template, matrix, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cfg_PrinterGlavni"], otvori_printaj));
     thread.Start();  }

And this is code that should do final work and open those files:
 public static void FindReplacePrint_T(string InputTemplate, Dictionary<string, string>[] placeholderValues_int, string Printer, string Primjeraka, string HEADER_UPP = "ne", string HEADER_IP = "ne")
{

   Kamion.MainWindow.StatusBarObrada("print_start");

    foreach (var placeholderValues in placeholderValues_int)
    {
       if(!placeholderValues.ContainsKey("<BANKA>")) { continue; }

      
       placeholderValues["<SJEDISTE>"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cfg_Sjediste"];
       
        // Create an instance of Word Application
        var wordApp = new Word.Word.Application();

        // Disable alerts and make the application invisible
        wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
        wordApp.Visible = false;
        if (Primjeraka == "0")
        {
            wordApp.Visible = true;
        }

        // Open the Word document
        try
        {
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@InputTemplate, missing, true);

            // Loop through the placeholder values dictionary
            foreach (var placeholder in placeholderValues)
            {
                // Find and replace placeholders with values
                Find findObject = wordApp.Selection.Find;
                findObject.ClearFormatting();
                findObject.Text = placeholder.Key;
                findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
                findObject.Replacement.Text = placeholder.Value;

                // Perform the find and replace operation
                object replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
                findObject.Execute(Replace: replaceAll);
            }

 
            // Print the document to the default printer
            if (Primjeraka != "0")
            {
                var praviDefault = doc.Application.ActivePrinter;

                doc.Application.ActivePrinter = Printer;

                doc.PrintOut(Background: false, Copies: Primjeraka);

                doc.Application.ActivePrinter = praviDefault;

                // Close the document without saving changes
                doc.Close(SaveChanges: false);
            }

            wordApp.NormalTemplate.Saved = true;


            if (Primjeraka != "0")
            {
                // Quit the Word application
                wordApp.Quit();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.ToString().Contains("deleted?"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fajl nije pronađen! Provjeriti folder sa templejtima.", "Greška!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Greška: " + ex, "Greška!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }

        }

        Kamion.MainWindow.StatusBarObrada("print_end");

    }

}

Please note that I am not professional and I do it just as Hobbie so code is probably not optimized and written in best possible practice but I would later work on optimization if I need it, right now I need it make work some how.
